# Append, Remove, Edit a Dictionary Item from List of Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I perform such task in a list of dictionary?

```
lists = [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'color': 'red'}]
```

(1) Append an item, {'age': '30'} to the current lists [0].

```
lists = [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'color': 'red', 'age': '30}]
```

(2) How do I change the 'lastname' to 'Smith'?

```
lists = [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'color': 'red', 'age': '30}]
```

(3) How do I remove the 'color' from the list?

```
lists = [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': '30}]
```

Comment: a profesor is the more appropriate place to ask for help with this i think... go to class, pay attention, read the assigned chapters, etc

Comment: I don't think you did an ounce of research before asking this question.

Comment: How did you know I didn't do my research?  Thank you to you both for useless comments.  Perhaps you can show me what you've learned by posting something useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lists = [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'color': 'red'}]

# update value to 30 
lists[0]["age"] = 30
print(lists)
# update value to smith
lists[0]["lastname"] = "Smith"
print(lists)
# finally delete using the del statement using the key
del lists[0]["color"]
print(lists)

[{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'age': 30, 'color': 'red'}]
[{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 30, 'color': 'red'}]
[{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 30}]
```

Comment: Thank you.  The whole time I was trying to use "append" for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would with any other dictionary. `lists[0]` is a dictionary.

(1) Appending:

```
lists[0]['age'] = '30'
```

(2) Modifying

```
lists[0]['lastname'] = 'Smith'
```

(3) Deleting

```
del lists[0]['color']
```

Comment: Thank you for the short and precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Append an item, {'age': '30'} to the current lists [0].

```
>>>lists[0]['age']=30
>>>lists
[{'age': 30, 'color': 'red', 'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'}]
```

(2) How do I change the 'lastname' to 'Smith'?

```
>>>lists[0]['lastname'] = "Smith"
>>>lists
[{'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 30, 'color': 'red', 'firstname': 'John'}]
```

(3) How do I remove the 'color' from the list?

```
>>>del lists[0]['color'] #or lists[0].pop('color') , This should return `red`
>>>lists
[{'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 30, 'firstname': 'John'}]
```

Comment: Not sure why or who but I do appreciate the answer.  Up voted for you.